# Print article with a Web-Crawler on Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am new with Python, and I am trying to make a Web-Crawler that print only the article (this website for example -http://techcrunch.com/2014/09/15/microsoft-has-acquired-minecraft/) and not the other things on the website. I tried this(and this doesn't work):

```
source_code = requests.get('http://techcrunch.com/2014/09/15/microsoft-has-acquired-minecraft/')
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

for link in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'article-entry text'}):
    title = link.string
    print(title)
```

And its print :'None'
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want only the article so insted of a `for` loop:

```
for link in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'article-entry text'}):
  title = link.string
  print(title)
```

Make it:

```
title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'alpha tweet-title'}).get_text()
article = soup.find('div', {'class': 'article-entry text'}.get_text()
print title
print article
```

You will get only the title and the article.

Documentation about [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) that could help.

Comment: Thx It's working. But Its print with <p> on the left and right and on differents lines. There is any way to get it without the <p> or maybe to get it in the same String?